# TensorFlow for image recognition, size of images

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, classification, image-recognition

How can size of an image effect training the model for this task?

My current training set holds images that are `2880 X 1800`, but I am worried this may be too large to train. In total my sample size will be about 200-500 images.

Would this just mean that I need more resources (GPU,RAM, Distribution) when training my model?

If this is too large, how should I go about resizing? -- I want to mimic real-world photo resolutions as best as possible for better accuracy.

**Edit:**

I would also be using `TFRecord` format for the image files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your memory and processing requirements will be proportional to the pixel size of your image. Whether this is too large for you to process efficiently will depend on your hardware constraints and the time you have available.

With regards to resizing the images there is no one answer, you have to consider how to best preserve information that'll be required for your algorithm to learn from your data while removing information that won't be useful. Reducing the size of your input images won't necessarily be a negative for accuracy. Consider two cases:

**Handwritten digits**

Here the images could be reduced considerably in size and maintain all the structural information necessary to be correctly identified. Have a look at the [MNIST data set](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/mnist/), these images are distributed at 28 x 28 resolution and identifiable to [99.7%+ accuracy](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.2745).

**Identifying Tree Species**

Imagine a set of images of trees where individual leaves could help identify species. Here you might find that reducing the image size reduces small scale detail on leaf shape in a way that's detrimental to the model, but you might find that you get a similar result with a tight crop (which preserves individual leaves) rather than an image resize. If this is the case you may find that creating multiple crops from the same image gives you an augmented data set for training that considerably improves results (which is something to consider, if possible, given your training set is very small)

Deep learning models are achieving results around human level in many image classification tasks: if you struggle to identify your own images then it's less likely you'll train an algorithm to. This is often a useful starting point when considering the level of scaling that might be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GPUs to train, this will def affect your training time. `Tensorflow` does most of the GPU allocation so you don't have to worry about that. But with big photos you will be experiencing long training time although your dataset is small. You should consider data-augmentation.

You could complement your resizing with the data-augmentation. Resize in equal dimensions and then perform reflection and translation (as in geometric movement)

Answer (score 1):

If your images are too big, your GPU might run out of memory before it can start training because it has to store the convolution outputs on its memory. If that happens, you can do some of the following things to reduce memory consumption:

- resize the image
- reduce batch size
- reduce model complexity

To resize your image, there are many scripts just one Google search away, but I will add that in your case 1440 by 900 is probably a sweet spot.

Answer (score 1):

Higher resolution images will result in a higher training time and an increased memory consumption (mainly GPU memory).

Depending on your concrete task, you might want to reduce the image size in order to therefore fit a reasonable batch size of let's say 32 or 64 on the GPU - for stable learning.

Your accuracy is probably affected more by the size of your training set. So instead of going for image size, you might want to go for 500-1000 sample images. Recent publications like [SSD - Single Shot MultiBox Detector](https://arxiv.org/abs/1512.02325) achieve high accuracy values like an mAP of 72% on the [PascalVOC](http://host.robots.ox.ac.uk/pascal/VOC/voc2012/index.html) dataset - with "only" using 300x300 image resolution.

Resizing and augmentation: SSD for instance just scales every input image down to 300x300, independent of the aspect ratio - does not seem to hurt. You could also augment your data by mirroring, translating, ... etc (but I assume there are built-in methods in Tensorflow for that).